# Rust (+SFML) - How to avoid extra object construction when limited by lifetime parameters?

Tags: sfml, rust, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

I'm using `rust-sfml` (`rsfml::graphics`) to, at the moment, draw pixels to the screen. (I'm just starting with both Rust and the project.) I'm storing the data in an `Image`, then copying to a `Texture`.

This `Texture` is used to create a [`Sprite<'s>`](http://www.rust-sfml.org/doc/rsfml/graphics/struct.Sprite.html); herein lies my problem. I need to be able to mutate the `Texture`, but the type of `Sprite<'s>` seems to guarantee that I can't do what I want. Since I need to be able to call `window.draw(&sprite)` every time the window is redrawn, I'm just creating a new `Sprite` each time.

The preferable alternative would keep the `Sprite<'s>` in my `struct Render` along with the `Texture`. Since 'Sprite' has a lifetime parameter, it becomes `struct Render<'s>`:

```
struct Render<'s> {
    texture: Texture,
    sprite: Sprite<'s>,
}
```

I have a method on `Render`:

```
fn blit(&'s mut self) -> ()
```

which mutates the `Render` (by editing the `Texture`). Now, as soon as I try to call `blit` more than once, I run into this problem:

```
render.blit();
render.blit();  // error: cannot borrow `render` as mutable more than once at a time
```

which, I think, happens because the lifetime parameter forces the the `Render`'s lifetime-as-borrowed-by-the-first-`blit`-call to be equal to the lifetime of the `Render` instance (the whole main function).

How can I keep my original `Sprite` and continue to be able to mutate the container? Is it possible?

Here is a stupid-looking and fairly minimal example:

```
extern crate rsfml;

use rsfml::graphics::Sprite;

fn main() -> () {
    let mut render = Render::new();
    render.blit();
    render.blit();  // error: cannot borrow `render` as mutable more than once at a time
}

struct Render<'s> {
    sprite: Option<Sprite<'s>>,
}

impl<'s> Render<'s> {
    fn new() -> Render { Render { sprite: None } }
    fn blit(&'s mut self) -> () { }
}
```

(Apologies if the question is not clear. It's difficult to express when I'm not very familiar with the concepts.)

Comment: That’s not making sense—if your code really *is* just `render.blit(); render.blit();`, then either neither would work or both would work. Can you post more complete code?

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I've made a semi-minimal example and attached it at the end.

Comment: FYI, the `-> ()` parts are superfluous, as is the `'s ` in your `blit` call.

Comment: Eww… the use of `'s ` in your `blit` definition is what’s causing it. It makes the borrow last longer. Of course, now I see it…

Comment: Well, the `'s` in the blit definition becomes needed (I think...) when I have actual code in there which uses `sprite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `blit`, there are two lifetimes under consideration; `self`, you see, is of type `&'ρ₀ Render<'ρ₁>` for certain lifetimes ρ₀ and ρ₁. In your `impl<'s> Render<'s>` declaration, you have declared that ρ₁ is `'s`, and in your `&'s mut self` you have declared that ρ₀ is `'s`: thus, the lifetime of the borrow of `self` *is `'s`*, which means that you can only ever have one borrow as it will survive until the destruction of the type—it has been declared as “at least as long as the type being referred to”.

You want to alter this to introduce a *new* lifetime parameter for the `blit` function which is permitted to be less than `'s`; you wish ρ₀ to be minimal, only tied to the return value (as I presume you are actually using `'s`—if not, you should just omit it and allow the compiler to infer what we’re about to write explicitly). This way, the borrow will only be active while the return value of the function is still in scope (in your trivial example, it’s not used and so you can immediately take another reference).

This, then, is the alteration to the function that needs to be done:

```
fn blit<'a>(&'a mut self) { }
```

If you alter this to have a return value and use it, you’ll need to make sure that it is out of scope before you call `blit` again. That may mean passing it directly to a function, or it may mean introducing a new scope, like this:

```
{
    let foo = render.blit();
    // … do things with foo … it then gets freed at the end of the block.
}
render.blit();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now running into another issue, which I guess was the root of the problem all along: If `blit` calls `self.sprite.set_texture(&self.texture, true)`, I get `error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements`. Should I edit the question? Make a new one?

Comment: I think you will find that bundling the sprite and texture together like this is something that can’t be expressed. You might like to discuss it in the Rust IRC channel (or probably better still, #rust-gamedev)

Comment: As it so happens, I'm going to the Rust Game Tech meetup at Mozilla tomorrow; so maybe being exposed to it will make everything clearer.

Comment: @KaiNinomiya: there will be people there to talk to about your problem!